# how to convert char to int in java for android

Tags: java, android

how to convert char to int in java for android

for example:

```
int MyInt;
char MyChar = 'A';
```

how to insert the value 65 into MyInt  ?

in C# it like: `MyInt = Convert.ToChar(MyChar);`

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it the same way in both C# and Java:

```
char myChar = 'A';
int myInt = myChar;
```

I wouldn't use `Convert.ToInt32` (which is what I assume you meant) in C#... I'd just use the implicit conversion shown above.

EDIT: In Java, this uses the implicit widening primitive conversion specified in [section 5.1.2 of the Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#5.1.2):

> The following 19 specific conversions on primitive types are called the widening primitive conversions:
>
> - byte to short, int, long, float, or double
> - short to int, long, float, or double
> - char to int, long, float, or double
> - [...]

Comment: Thenks for the help, and how to convert string to char ?

Comment: @goldsoft: You can get a *single* character from a string using `String.charAt`. Obviously if the string has more than one character, you need to decide which one you mean...